# ruby readline nested autocompletion base on previous element

Tags: ruby

Hello I am struggling with code which provide autocompletion base on standard readline library

I tested scenario base on readline documentation example:

```
LIST = [
  'search', 'download', 'open',
  'help', 'history', 'quit',
  'url', 'next', 'clear',
  'prev', 'past'
].sort

comp = proc { |s| LIST.grep(/^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/) }

Readline.completion_append_character = " "
Readline.completion_proc = comp

while line = Readline.readline('> ', true)
  p line
end
```

I plan to created nested autocompletion for previously "tabbed" element if exist

like for example lets look on 1 element on list "search", I want to create separated data structure which will hold subcommands for search and allow only elements confirmed to have options to be able to autocomplete base on source element

like search + tab = search instances

for now I tried to play with proc without success and with nested readline

any idea how to implement that ?

Comment: Tip: For long lists of single words in an array use `%w[ search download ... ]` which splits on whitespace for you. Saves a lot of punctuation.

Comment: Does the auto-complete hook provide enough context to do what you want?

Comment: @tadman thanks for tip, regarding hook (proc If I understand correctly) I tried to check if currently typed element matches to key on another structure, but without success, I guess I failed on design

Comment: You may want to write some simple test cases here (e.g. Rspec?) to verify your method is working correctly before assuming it does and moving on to integrating it. You could also make a dummy auto-complete method that always suggests the same thing to verify you're doing it correctly.